# Read Timeout when connecting to AWS ElastiCache redis through spring boot app runnig on aws ec2 instance

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I'm running a spring boot app as a Docker container on EC2 instance.
I've created a redis cluster (ElastiCache on AWS) and enabled encryption in-transit as well as at rest.

Everything is proper in terms of VPC and security group configurations.
The issue is, when I see spring boot app logs it's throwing

```
    redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:147)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:211)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getRawObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:242)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:248)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.scan(BinaryJedis.java:3284)
    at org.eclipse.leshan.server.cluster.RedisRegistrationStore$RedisIterator.scanNext(RedisRegistrationStore.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.leshan.server.cluster.RedisRegistrationStore$RedisIterator.<init>(RedisRegistrationStore.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.leshan.server.cluster.RedisRegistrationStore.getAllRegistrations(RedisRegistrationStore.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.leshan.server.impl.RegistrationServiceImpl.getAllRegistrations(RegistrationServiceImpl.java:57)
    at dishac.server.management.RequestProcessorEngine$Scanner.run(RequestProcessorEngine.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
    ... 19 more
```

I'm sure, redis cluster is reachable because I have another redis cluster with same configuration except for encryption in-transit and at-rest is disabled is working fine for me.

Here is my docker file snap (I'm using ENV variables instead of application.yml):

ENV SPRING_REDIS_HOST m.d-r-s.us.usblahe2.cblhaahe.amazonaws.com
ENV SPRING_REDIS_SSL true
ENV SPRING_REDIS_PASSWORD blahblahblahblah
ENV SPRING_REDIS_JEDIS_POOL_MAX_ACTIVE 8
ENV SPRING_REDIS_JEDIS_POOL_MAX_IDLE 8
ENV SPRING_REDIS_JEDIS_POOL_MAX_WAIT -1ms
ENV SPRING_REDIS_JEDIS_POOL_MIN_IDLE 0

Update: I tried with stunnel from same ec2 instance(where java spring boot app is running) and I'm able to access the redis cluster.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Doe anyone know solutions for this?

Comment: The issue is with library I'm using for connection, it does not support SSL or does not work well with its current version. Sorry for late reply. Try some other library with proper SSL support it should work.